# microsoft.rtc.collaboration 32 bit

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, ucma

i understand that the UCMA 3.0 SDK only comes as 64 bit version, but why isn't there a 3.0 version of the microsoft.rtc.collaboration assembly for 32 bit available. I understand, that the 64 bit area has already been started but 32 bit is not yet dead.
Am I just blind or is there no 32 bit version available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for completeness: there is no 32 bit version available.